# Get files and changed lines from Subversion diff using Python

Tags: python, svn, diff

For a pre-commit hook I need to run an analysis script on all the changed lines in a Subversion working copy. For that I need to find out which lines were changed by parsing the output of svn diff.

Is there an easy (canonical) way, or an existing script, that will do this in Python?

Comment: SVN has a diff parser if you want the diff parsed, see my answer on this question for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381507/whats-the-best-way-to-turn-a-subversion-diff-into-json/20413989#20413989

Answer (score 0):

You will find it much easier to use the output from `svnlook diff` than `svn diff` use it with the repo and transaction that are available to the hook as parameters.

You might find it worth exploring [pysnv](http://pysvn.tigris.org/) to be able to access svn directly in python.

Comment: I think pysvn is overkill for what I want to achieve. If I'll have to write something from scratch, it's probably not going to exceed 100 lines - I was just wondering if there is someone out there who already did it.